# Chef: Install multiple Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, chef-infra

I am using Chef to deploy Wordpress Sites on a single node. I am using a wrapper recipe on top of Supermarkets "[Wordpress recipe](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/wordpress)". I am not sure how to tell my wrapper cookbook to install the wordpress files on multiple directories: Here si the attribute needs to be set to define the install dir

```
node['wordpress']['dir'] = '<path for the install dir'
```

I have tried putting this block in default attribute file but it only installs at the last folder not the first 3 folders.

```
default['apps'] = ['app1', 'app2, 'app3', 'app4']
default['apps'].each do |app|

    node.default['wordpress']['dir'] = "/home/wordpress-user/#{app}"

end
```

I also tried something like this in my recipe file

This is how I am trying to create the folders:

```
 node['apps'].each do |app|
  directory "/home/wordpress-user/#{app}" do
  owner node['wordpress']['user']
  group node['wordpress']['group']
  mode '0755'
  action :create
  Chef::Log.info "App files will be installed under /home/wordpress-user/#{app}"
  not_if { File.exist?("/home/wordpress-user/#{app}")}
  end
end
```

and then I am trying to tell it to install the wordpress files in a loop

```
 node.default['apps'].each do |app|
     node.override['wordpress']['dir'] = "/home/wordpress-user/#{app}"
 end
```

But somehow this is not working. I am sure I am doing something wrong. I am very new to Chef. Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your case I would write wordpress recipe from scratch, because what have you described will save attribute node['wordpress']['dir'] = "/home/wordpress-user/app4", because it overrides existing attribute.
Please check out [attributes section](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html).

I would use:

```
node.default['apps'].each do |app|
  node.override['wordpress']['dir'][app] = "/home/wordpress-user/#{app}"

  directory node['wordpress']['dir'][app] do
    owner node['wordpress']['user']
    group node['wordpress']['group']
    mode '0755'
    action :create
    Chef::Log.info "App files will be installed under /home/wordpress-user/#{app}"
    not_if { File.exist?(node['wordpress']['dir'][app])}
  end

  bash "extract wp code to #{app}" do
    cwd node['wordpress']['dir'][app]
    code "tar -zxf #{sourcecode}"
  end
end
```

Best regards,
Alexey

On your case I would configure each app separately in apache configuration , configuring database and extracting wordpress sources.